# How do I bulk download images (70k) from urls with a restriction on the simultaneous downloads?

Tags: python, image, url, download, bulk

I'm a bit clueless. I have a csv file with these columns: name - picture url
I would like to bulk download the 70k images into a folder, rename the images with the name in the first column and number them if there is more than one per name.
Some are jpegs some are pngs.

I'm guessing I need to use pandas to get the data from the csv but I don't know how to make the downloading/renaming part without starting  all the downloads at the same time, which will for sure crash my computer (It did, I wasn't even mad).
Thanks in advance for any light you can shed on this.

Comment: An example of a few lines of your CSV might help. As would knowing what Operating System you use.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading in batches like 500 images...then sleep for some 1 seconds and loop it....quite time consuming...but sure fire method....for the coding reference you can explore packges like urllib (for downloading) and as soon as u download the file use os.rename() to change the name....As u already know for that csv file use pandas...

Answer (score -1):

I'm a coding idiot . . . so take this with a pinch of salt.

I needed to take a CSV in (column 1 with URL, Column 2 with filename) and put it in an existing folder in the directory that the code was running.

Worked like a charm for me. Maybe something here helps

```
#import Libraries
import csv
import urllib.request

# Function to download file from URL to a SPECIFIED FOLDER with a SPECIFIED NAME
def dl_jpg(url, file_path, file_name):  
  full_path = file_path + file_name + '.jpg' 
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)

# Get CSV File-name and Folder to store images from the user
file_name = input('Please enter filename:  ')
folder_name = input('Please enter a folder name:  ')

# Open SPECIFIED CSV and iterate through the URL on each line and call the Download function for each Line and filename.
with open(file_name + '.csv','r') as csv_file:  
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(csv_reader)
    for line in csv_reader:  
      print(line[0])
      dl_jpg(line[0],folder_name +'/', line[1])
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow @Cubic. Your solution might be helpful, but you need to clearly explain how it addresses the question. Here the question is 'how to perform the downloads sequentially, as opposed to in parallel'. If your solution does that, great, but you need to explain it. If it doesn't, then you're not answering the question. Thanks